# MaxUploadSizeExceededException not thrown in tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit, multipartform-data

I have a simple spring app, with a controller that expects multipart file. For testing purpose I have set the `MaxUploadSize` size to just 50 bytes. When I deploy the war in tomcat I get the expected `MaxUploadSizeExceededException` for larger files, but if I use the same file in unit test then the test does not work.

---

Config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {...})
public class MyApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

  @Bean
  public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver =
        new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    commonsMultipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
    commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(50);
    return commonsMultipartResolver;
  }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/metadata")
public class MyController {

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE,
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public String metadata(@RequestParam MultipartFile file)  {
     //some processing...
  }
}
```

Test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
public class MyControllerTest {
...
@Test
  public void testDocx() throws Exception {
    byte[] docx = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(
            "src/test/resources/testdocs/test.docx"));
    MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("file", "test.docx", "", docx);
    this.mvc.perform(fileUpload("/metadata").file(multipartFile))
        .andDo(print()).andExpect(status().is5xxServerError()); 
   //doesn't work, returns 200
  }
}
```

Spring version: 4.1.6

Comment: Checking of upload size - doing by application server. Look at the exception: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$FileSi‌​zeLimitExceededExcep‌​tion.`
But tests dont deal with real application server.

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into the same issue and fortunately I was able to solve it.

I assume `this.mvc` is a instance of `MockMvc`. Accordingly [spring](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/) documentation:

> Another useful approach is to not start the server at all but to test
>   only the layer below that, where Spring handles the incoming HTTP
>   request and hands it off to your controller. That way, almost of the
>   full stack is used, and your code will be called in exactly the same
>   way as if it were processing a real HTTP request but without the cost
>   of starting the server. To do that, use Spring’s MockMvc and ask for
>   that to be injected for you by using the @AutoConfigureMockMvc
>   annotation on the test case.

Since there is no server started and this exception is thrown by Tomcat, it will never be thrown. I just had to remove it and use [TestRestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-with-running-server) for calling the endpoint and worked like a charm. There is a fine example [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/).